# Can not open ServiceStack mvc project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, servicestack

I can not open ServiceStack Mvc project on visual studio 2012. This error message appears:

[image]

I've installed "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package" and same message appears again. Do you know how to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: A photo is in "enter image description here" link